# How taking the value of a href attr in a div

Tags: javascript

I have a link, how can i get the value of the alt attr in my href ? (1)

```
<div class="user_line">
<img class="delete_user" src="images/close_button_mini.gif">
<a class="chat_user" alt="1|Test" href="#">Test</a>
</div>

// With $this
$('.delete_user').live('click',function(){
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry i've edited my post, i added the element. i forgot .

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this problem? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: `$('.chat_user').attr('alt')`

Comment: I need with $this please ^^

Comment: @user3162341: Honestly, this is terribly simple. You've really got to take the time to learn at least the basics of the tools you use.

Comment: @user3162341 - why don't you try the solution that @adeneo offered and try changing it to using `$this`... and see what happens... then tell us if you get an error message. ie - don't wait for us to tell you how to make it work - try it yourself first

Answer (score 0):

you can take the alt like this

```
var alt=$('.chat_user').attr('alt');
```